# JDBCTemplate not fetching records more than 1500

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am using JDBCTemplate for fetching the records...my table have 46,000 rows that I want to wrap in a user type object using rowmapper.

But when I try below code it shows " Executing SQL query [Select USER_ID,Desc from Q7.USERBSC_INFO where STAT_CD='ACTIVE']" and after that nothing happened..I waited for 15 minutes but still showed nothing..but application still working...no exception

I am using JCC drivers of DB2, this is a mainframe DB2

But when I run the query for only 1500 records it work fine...is there any limitation for fetching records?

When I run the same query inside AQT client, it works fine...

```
public List<usr> getusr() {
        List<usr> list = new ArrayList<usr>();
        String query = "Select USER_ID,Desc from Q7.USERBSC_INFO where STAT_CD='ACTIVE'";

list = getJdbcTemplate().query(query, DB2RowMapper.mUsrInfo);

        return list;
    }
```

RowMapper

```
 public static RowMapper mUsrInfo = new RowMapper()
                {
                    public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
                    {

                        Usr usr=new Usr();
                        usr.setUsrId(rs.getString("USER_ID"));
                        usr.setDesc(rs.getString("DESC"));
                        return usr;

                    }
                };
```

Comment: During those 15 minutes of "working" -- is there any CPU usage? Can you run the code under a debugger, e.g. from an IDE?

Comment: I noticed one thing that when I try to fetch upto 1637 record it works fine but if I use 1638 it gives below error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.DisconnectException: dss length not 0 at end of same id chain parse

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the no of records in spring Jdbc Template(using a maxRows options) but in don't think that's the case here. 
I guess the no of records()46000 that are being fetched is the reason for this delay...

You can either try optimizing your query or else try using this clause at the end may be it might help

```
OPTIMIZE FOR n ROWS
```

Comment: When I try to fetch 1638 records it says below error:com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.DisconnectException: dss length not 0 at end of same id chain parse